# Django: Converting uuid value to a string in django template engine

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

I have this code of line that I need to be up and running.

```
<h4 class="page-header">
    {% if msg.sent_by_id == request.user.public_id|string %}
        {% if request.user.role == 'administrator' %}Admin Replied
        {% elif request.user.role == 'user' %}Your reply
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
</h4>
```

The problem is that these two values are the same, BUT both of them are other format. `msg.sent_by_id` is a string, neither `request.user.public_id`, this value is in `uuid` format. What is the correct way of 'converting' an variable to a string and then comparing the two values?

Comment: `str (uuid)` in your view and pass the str version into your template

Comment: I'm passing the whole json object -`return render(request, 'service_desk/ticket_status.html', {'ticket': Ticket_obj, 'ticket_messages': Ticket_obj_messages})`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the string format template tag https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat

```
{% if msg.sent_by_id == request.user.public_id|stringformat:"s" %}
```